# How to have a pointer to a table from a table entry?

Tags: sqlalchemy, mariadb, mysql-python

Imagine we have 100 IoT devices collecting data every 5 seconds. We have a central table with 100 entries -- one per IoT device. The entries have columns such as name, battery, longitude, latitude.

I now want a column that points me to a new records table. There is a records table for each IoT device. This table holds the time-value pairs for the measurements that this specific device collects.

My questions are:

1- Is this the right way of thinking?

2- Can I automatically generate these tables as I insert entries to the central table?

3- Is there a pointer notion that enables me to be redirected to a table?

I am new to SQL, and I use MariaDB and SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Generally no, a single records table is usually sufficient. Include a sample of the sort of queries for the IoT records and then you can make sure its indexed correctly for use.

Comment: Further to comment from @danblack - If your design involves multiple separate tables per "thing" and all of those tables are to have an identical structure then your design is faulty. You want to create a single table with that structure plus an additional Foreign Key column to hold the unique identifier (Primary Key) of each "thing" in the "central table".

Answer (score 0):

You should not create separate table for each device. You need to create single table for all measurements:

```
create table devices (
    id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(64),
    battery varchar(64), 
    longitude decimal(5, 2),
    latitude decimal(5, 2)
);

create table measurements (
    device_id int unsigned references devices(id) on delete cascade ,
    measurement_type int,
    value int,
    index device_idx (device_id)
);
```

[SQL online](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/6aca926d12cb913528dba6d83db2898c/)

In high-load case you can use table partitioning